# Nodeclipse cannot debug

Tags: node.js, nodeclipse

I'm new to NodeJS. I tried start with Eclipse + Nodeclipse&Endie 2015 as IDE for my experiment. However, when I tried with debug "Debug As -> Node Application", the exception keep showing.
[Exception from Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCJVF.png)

I tried with other answers around but non of them work. Much appreciate if you can give advice for this.

Answer (score 0):

I exactly have the same problem. It seems that a similar error has been reported on github (the nodeclipse project): https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/107. It has been transfered to the issue #220. It still doesn't solve my problem though... But you can keep track of this ticket!

It seems related to the fact that npm change its command line interface and does not accept the --debug parameter, but now expect --inspect. But the plugin didn't change at that time. A commit has been done to fix that problem.